# R: apply and nchar with if condition

Tags: r, function, if-statement, apply

I am trying to write a test for my data to print if there are any strings longer than 9 characters long in a column of a dataframe.

When using apply, I get confused as to how have it run nchar as a function with an if statement. I thought it would be something like this:

```
apply(df$a, 2, function(x) if nchar(x>9), nchar(x))
```

However I get an error: unexpected symbol in...

What am I missing here?

Comment: `if(nchar(x>9)  nchar(x))` lose the comma and `if` is a function

Comment: `nchar` is vectorized, so you just need `any(nchar(df$a) > 9)`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For a single column, to test if there are any strings longer than 9

```
any(nchar(df$a) > 9)
```

If you want to check every column

```
sapply(df, function(x) any(nchar(x) > 9))
```

If you want to see the rows for a single column

```
df$a[nchar(df$a) > 9]  # a values only
df[nchar(df$a) > 9, ]  # entire rows
```

Test data:

```
df = data.frame(a = c("alsdfsaj", "alksdjfaklsjfaskjf", "aklsdj"),
                b = c("b", "bbb", "bbbb"),
                stringsAsFactors = F)
```

Comment: the option to see the rows: df$a[nchar(df$a) > 9, ] doesnt work, I get an Error for incorrect number of dimensions. Gregor, any suggestions?